# What to do with wires from old outdoor light?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I'm permanently removing an old stair light from a porch.  I've disconnected the fixture but the wires come from the house through a hole in the wall.  So now I have about 2 feet of wire hanging from the wall under the porch. I've put wire nuts on the end but that doesn't seem like a permanent solution. What should I do with it?

Comment: Is there a box where the hole in the wall is?

Comment: No, really just a hole drilled through the exterior wall of the house.

Comment: The "wire" is UF I take it?

Comment: What is "UF"?..

Comment: UF = Underground Feeder cable (aka "outdoor Romex")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two "proper" solutions. First, you could install a box rated for the location (dry, damp, wet). Terminate the wires in the box, and install an appropriate blank cover.

The other option is to find where the wires originate, and disconnect them. Then you can either tuck the wires back into the hole in the wall, or if possible remove the wires altogether.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll probably go with the box just in case I need the wire in the future.  So is installing it just a matter of screwing it into the wall?  Do I even need to connect the wires to any terminals inside?

Comment: You can simply cap the wires off inside the box.  If the box is in a location where it will get damp/wet, you'll have to use a box and cover rated for damp/wet locations.